# Performance for compound boolean vs. unlikely/likely

Tags: c++, if-statement, optimization, conditional-statements

Is doing this faster?:

```
return m_bVisible && (_colorTransform.alphaTransform > 0 || _colorTransform.colorOffsetTransform.a > 0) && (!_masked || _maskVisitable);
```

Than doing this?:

```
if (UNLIKELY(_colorTransform.alphaTransform == 0 && _colorTransform.colorOffsetTransform.a == 0))
{
    return false;
}

if (UNLIKELY(_masked && !_maskVisitable))
{
    return false;
}

return m_bVisible;
```

Doing a lot of minor optimizations which have improved framerate performance significantly for our game, here's one that I'm unsure of. I'm ok with getting 0.01% performance gain since after doing 100 of these optimizations, I've been able to improve performance quite significantly(30-40%). Asking about the use of UNLIKELY optimization vs. just the compound boolean. Short circuiting isn't very easy to do in this particular expression.

Comment: Measuring is crap! I would compile both versions and see how the assembler code looks in both of these examples (branch prediction).

My first hunch is that the first one is more efficient!

Comment: For measuring, it's very hard to see the results if impact is below 1%, the rendering code has a lot of things animating and moving which impacts any successive runs. Successive runs on this code keeps bouncing between 1-2%, it's pretty volatile regardless if I don't change code. And I don't think a simple test would work since it works better with real world values of what is likely and unlikely.

Comment: I suppose that this code used in a loop. Modify that code, so the loop runs multiple times. If that loop has something which takes a lot of time, comment it out (or comment out the body of the functions it calls - it's a better solution, as the loop will be intact). Then measure the difference. This question can only be decided by measuring. The accepted answer simply doesn't give any proof of its claims. It just says "seems". The speed of this code largely dependent on the data, and therefore branch prediction, which cannot be decided by just looking at the assembly.

Comment: Btw., if you have a lot of invisible objects, you maybe want to put visible objects into a separate list, and manage it, as visibility/alpha changes. This way you don't have to process a lot of invisible objects.

Comment: Making the code work more times is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the first one is faster!

Even though you are "optimizing" branch prediction on the second one, that basically just means that `return m_bVisible;` will come earlier in the ASM code than your `return false`, you still have to do up to four comparisons in your if statements.

However, since they are highly UNLIKELY, as you say, there is no need to do that before actually taking a look at `m_bVisible`. The first example checks for `m_bVisible` first, which does not seem to be have a bias towards either FALSE or TRUE.

My hunch is, that for all cases where `m_bVisible == false`, the first one will be faster. In all other cases, there will be not much difference except for the minimal overhead of JMP's in the second example (which require you to jump past `return m_bVisible;` to get to the actual `return false`).

## EDIT

Let us have a deeper look at the x86_64 assemblies (gcc 8) of both variants:

Test Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

bool a=true; int b=0; int c=0; bool d=false; bool e=true;
#define likely(x)       __builtin_expect((x),1)
#define unlikely(x)     __builtin_expect((x),0)

int main()
{
marker1:
    return a && (b > 0 || c > 0) && (!d || e);
}


int alternative()
{
    if (unlikely(b == 0 && c == 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (unlikely(d && !e))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return a;
}
```

X86_86 Assember (GCC 8.2) for both functions:

main()

```
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR a[rip]
    test    al, al
    je      .L3
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR b[rip]
    test    eax, eax
    jg      .L4
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR c[rip]
    test    eax, eax
    jle     .L3
.L4:
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR d[rip]
    xor     eax, 1
    test    al, al
    jne     .L5
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR e[rip]
    test    al, al
    je      .L3
.L5:
    mov     eax, 1
    jmp     .L6
.L3:
    mov     eax, 0
.L6:
    movzx   eax, al
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

alternative()

```
alternative():
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR b[rip]
    test    eax, eax
    sete    al
    movzx   eax, al
    test    rax, rax
    je      .L9
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR c[rip]
    test    eax, eax
    sete    al
    movzx   eax, al
    test    rax, rax
    je      .L9
    mov     eax, 0
    jmp     .L10
.L9:
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR d[rip]
    movzx   eax, al
    test    rax, rax
    je      .L11
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR e[rip]
    xor     eax, 1
    movzx   eax, al
    test    rax, rax
    je      .L11
    mov     eax, 0
    jmp     .L10
.L11:
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR a[rip]
    movzx   eax, al
.L10:
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

In the first variant, in main(), the quickest exit is at the fifth line, `je      .L3`. In the second variant, the quickest exit occurs a lot later ... in .L9 at `je      .L11`

## EDIT2

Just to have it complete, here the assembly for -O3

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     BYTE PTR a[rip], 0
        je      .L1
        cmp     DWORD PTR b[rip], 0
        jle     .L10
.L4:
        cmp     BYTE PTR d[rip], 0
        mov     eax, 1
        je      .L1
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR e[rip]
.L1:
        ret
.L10:
        cmp     DWORD PTR c[rip], 0
        jg      .L4
        ret
```

And

```
alternative():
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR b[rip]
        or      eax, DWORD PTR c[rip]
        je      .L11
        cmp     BYTE PTR d[rip], 0
        jne     .L18
.L13:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR a[rip]
        ret
.L18:
        cmp     BYTE PTR e[rip], 0
        jne     .L13
        xor     eax, eax
.L11:
        ret
```

Even with inlining, the first one still seems to be quicker at O3!

Comment: I think that's mostly correct. Unfortunately, even though it is LIKELY that m_bVisible is true, we still need to check the very unlikely events. This function is inlined, so I don't actually think there should be jmps in the ASM. I wonder what it actually reduces too once inlined.

Comment: I guess we should compile that and have a look at the assembler then :) I am at it!

Comment: Added the x86_64 assembly to my answer ... getting a coffee before looking at it!

Comment: Bump! Was incomplete!

Comment: To me, it looks like the ASM confirms what we already knew (see answer). What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Bump! Now, Added the O3 variant with inlining as you suggested! I think the first one is still quicker!

Comment: Ok O3 is still slower by a lot, thank you! That was very helpful.